# Changing the color of an iTextSharp Checkbox AcroField

Tags: c#, pdf, itext, acrofields

I'm trying to populate a form with a few AcroFields using iTextSharp. There are a couple of text fields and a checkbox field, and by default the fields are filled out in blue. I'd like these fields to be filled out in black.

Changing the textfields using the following works:

```
form.SetFieldProperty("textboxname", "textcolor", Color.BLACK, null);
```

[image]

However, trying to do the same for the checkbox doesn't work:

```
form.SetFieldProperty("checkboxname", "textcolor", Color.BLACK, null);
```

[image]

Any insights? Thanks!

Comment: the SetFieldProperty() methods of iTextSharp seem to work only for textboxes and buttons (not only color, but generally).
If you use a "template"-pdf you could change it in the pdf-file with Adobe-Acrobat. If you are generating the pdf in the code I sadly can't help you (but have the same problem, so let me know if you find something)